# Wix File Association: How to set the default action?

Tags: wix

I want to do something similar to what was done [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048311/wix-creating-multiple-associations-for-single-file-type) where I have a single custom file type but multiple user actions associated with it. My question is how do I set one to be the "Default" action? For example when I double click it, which is the default action that is performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verb Id="Open" is default action or the double click action.